# Database of the website "eMovies"

Tags: database-design

Here is my exercise:

> Given database of the website "eMovies" that manage data about cinema movies. build the given database in Access and create the relationships between the tables.

[image]

My attempt:

[image]

My questions:

1. I am not sure at all about the relationships that I made between the tables at all.
2. I am not sure about the keys

---

EDIT: After asking my doctor the table and the keys are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check on the theory behind the definition of the objects that you got. There lies the answer to your second question and even your first question could be answered by that. There is no difference between the keys for left and right tables. If you think about the order? Depends on how you use them. Which is the 'direction' in which you want to access them? That is the first one of the composite key.

Answer (score 3):

Begin with the question, **what is your requirement?** based on your question, you need to develope a relational database for managing movies data.

Before starting to build a database, you have to ask a lot of questions to understand about how the movies business work within the requirement scope. Lets start with the question,

**Who is important to your movies business?**

Based on the question, **ACTOR, DIRECTOR.**

**What is important to movies business?**

**GENRES, MOVIE.**

Now, the next question will be **what is the definition of ACTOR, DIRECTOR, GENRES, MOVIES?**

For example, *An ACTOR is a human being, who acts in atleast one movie.* Note that you should have a clear definition of entity (business concept) or else it will lead to multiple interpretation. (see [here](http://cstechie.blogspot.in/2015/12/conceptual-data-model.html?m=0)).

After understanding the business concepts, let us go for business rules. Some simple questions (based on your question).

- Can an Actor act in more than one Film?
- Can a Movie coontains more than one Actor?
- Can a Movie directed by more than one Director?
- Can a Movie categorized as more than one Genre?

Example business rule from your question.

- Each Actor can act in one or many Actor Movie.
- Each Actor Movie must be acted by one Actor.
- Each Movie can contain one or many Actor Movie.
- Each Actor Movie must belongs to one Movie.
- Each Directos can direct one or many Director Movie.
- Each Director Movie must be directed by one Director.
- Each Movie can contain one or many Director Movie.
- Each Director Movie must belongs to one Movie.
- Each Genres can contain one or many Genres Movie.
- Each Genres Movie must belongs to one Genres.
- Each Movie can contain one or many Genre Movie.
- Each Genre Movie must belongs to one Movie.

By applying these business rules, our new model may look like as follows: 
[image: eMovies data model]

This model is not normalized, after applying **normalization** (see [here](http://cstechie.blogspot.in/2016/01/what-is-database-normalization.html?m=0)) process, you will have clear and detailed data model for your application.

I hope this model will help you to begin your assignment. Thank you.